# Check for value of variable after every looping (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop, do-while

OK, so let me start by saying I'm a nob IOS developer who just very recently learned to code in Swift. I don't know anything about PHP but I'm writing basic scripts for my web services. Please bear with me if my question sounds stupid.

Here's what I'm trying to do: I'm retrieving data from my MySQL database and I'm assigning the retrieved data, the value of a certain column from a certain row from my MySQL table, to a variable `$retrievedStatus`. After that, I'm starting a `do while` loop and I want that loop to keep running as long as the retrieved value from the MySQL table is equal to a certain value I'm listening for. In code, it looks something like this:

```
// CREATE DATABASE CONNECTION
$db = new DbConnect('localhost', 'myusername', 'mypassword', 'mydatabase');
$db->show_errors();

// DECODE PHP INPUT (WILL RECEIVE INPUT FROM CLIENT SIDE WHICH WILL BE USED TO CHECK STATUS)
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$data = json_decode($json, true);
$id = $data['idToCheck'];
$username = $data['usernameToCheck'];
$retrievedStatus = ""; // <-- CREATING A STRING OBJECT OUTSIDE THE DO BLOCK EVEN THOUGH I ASSIGN A VALUE TO IT INSIDE THE DO BLOCK. I DO THIS SO I CAN CHECK UPON THE VALUE AFTER THE DO BLOCK HAS FINISHED AND IT CHECKS FOR THE WHILE CONDITION TO SEE IF IT SHOULD REPEAT

do {

    // Sleep for 5 seconds
    sleep(5);

    // SQL query to retrieve status
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id = '" . $id . "' AND username = '" . $username . "'";
    $result = $db->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        // Assign each row into an array
        $dataArray[] = $row;
    }

    // Get status from returned row: ONLY 1 ROW WAS RETURNED
    $jsonArray = json_encode($dataArray);
    $decodedArray = json_decode($jsonArray, true);
    $userDictionary = $decodedArray[0];
    $retrievedStatus = $userDictionary['status']; // <-- THIS IS WHERE THE VALUE GETS ASSIGNED TO THE STRING OBJECT I CREATED EARLIER

    // DOWN HERE SOME CODE IS EXECUTED TO RETURN DATA BOTH BACK TO THE CLIENT AND THE SERVER

} while ($retrievedStatus != "connected") // AS LONG AS THE COLUMN status IN MY SQL TABLE IS NOT EQUAL TO "connected" THIS LOOP WILL CONTINUE RUNNING AND IT WILL REPEAT THE PROCESS OF UPDATING THE STATUS AND DOING THE DATA TASK AFTERWARDS
```

Here's the issue: I've tested the code and as soon as the client side triggers the above code to start running via a data task, it receives back the data from the web service (the one inside the `do` block) every 5 seconds (notice the web service sleeps for 5 seconds during every loop) so the loop works perfectly. The problem is that as soon as the column `status` in my MYSQL table is changed to "connected" the loop should stop repeating, because the while condition will be false. It doesn't do this however and instead, it just keeps running forever (infinite loop), which means something obviously goes wrong when the return value from the SQL query gets assigned to `$retrievedStatus`. I learned in Swift you can't access a variable from outside the code block where it was first created, so that's why I created the empty string variable before the `do` block. Was this necessary and/or was this the right way to do it? I hope my explanation on what I'm trying achieve is clear enough, and I hope someone can help me out with this. Thanks!